# Why does the Rasteriser take up so much frame time?

Tags: game-engine

Having just downloaded the BGE, I have set up a simple scene with a rigid body cube and a plane, they both interact as expected, but when measuring frametime I register stable 45 FPS, as per in the image. The Rasterizer takes up 94% of all the frametime, lasting over 20ms. This doesn't happen in other softwares. Why is it happening? I tried using the Viewport Renderer and it works perfectly fast. I have uploaded the scene onto a link for sharing: https://easyupload.io/c6x94s. If you can help it'd be greatly appreciated. Here's a screenshot too: https://imgur.com/a/P8QEhmR.

Comment: Try tagging your question 'upbge'. - The game engine was removed from Blender with version 2.8 and is maintained seperately nowadays.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.